# How to retrieve DTO from wrapper method?

Tags: java, string, return, dto

I have one getter in method and I'm wrapping getName with nameTransform method to make it check for validation that I need

```
public InvoiceRequestDTO orderTransformer(OrderDTO orderDTO)  {

        return new InvoiceRequestDTO(nameTransform(orderDTO.getName());

    }
```

And one method for checking

```
private String nameTransform(String name) {
        if (orderDTO.getName().length() < 1) {
            orderDTO.setName("0000" + orderDTO.getName());
        }
        if (orderDTO.getName().length() < 2) {
            orderDTO.setName("000" + orderDTO.getName());
        }
        if (orderDTO.getName().length() < 3) {
            orderDTO.setName("00" + orderDTO.getName());
        }
        if (orderDTO.getName().length() < 4) {
            orderDTO.setName("0" + orderDTO.getName());
        }
        else orderDTO.getName();

        return nameTransform(name);
    }
```

How to retrieve orderDTO in the method nameTransofm? When I'm doing

```
OrderDTO orderDTO = new OrderDTO();
```

It gives me null pointer exception

Comment: Where are you getting the exception ? Please provide the stack trace.

Comment: When I put Order DTO orderDTO = new Order DTO() in nameTransform method and run application, it gives me nullpointerexception

Comment: I suspect that when you are trying to access `orderDTO.getName().length()` you are getting a NullPointerException since getName returns null. Try to debug and check why the DTO or name attribute is not getting populated when the control comes to the nameTransform method

Comment: I'm debugging it, when we make OrderDTO orderDTO = new OrderDTO() in nameTransform method it tries to initialize new Order, so that's why it is without name or etc. That's my question, how to get OrderDTO from above first method? My nameTransform method accepts String name

Comment: If I'll change it, then I'll have error with `nameTransform(orderDTO.getName()` it requires just String parameter

Comment: your code is quite messed up... isn't it? to what does `orderDTO` refer in `nameTransform()`?

Comment: Inside a method, you can access variables that are defined in the method, class and the parameters that are passed to that method only. You have to choose one of these approaches. Either pass it as a parameter to the method, or, if both the methods are in the same class, define `orderDTO` as a class variable and access it in the required methods. Alternatively, you can define a public getter and setter method and try to access the object using that

Comment: @Lino, I want to wrap OrderDTO.getName with method nameTransform. In that method I want to check all names are valid. But I don't know how to get ordetDTO in the nameTransform method, because it has String parameter

Comment: Why not change signature of `nameTransform(String)` to `nameTransform(OrderDTO)`?

Comment: @JohnNewell if you are only going to check the name, why bother passing the whole DTO at all ? just use `name.length()...` in your method. You already have it as a parameter in the method.

Comment: @Lino Because when I'll change it, `return new InvoiceRequestDTO(nameTransform(orderDTO.getName());` gives me an error that is cannot be applied to a String

Comment: @Arpit, OK, I'll check the name length, but how to make name.getName and name.setName after that?

Comment: What can not be applied to string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i have understood your intents correctly, this should do the trick:

```
private String nameTransform(OrderDTO orderDTO) {
    String name = orderDTO.getName();
    String newName;
    int length = name.length();

    if (length < 1) {
        newName = "0000" + name;
    }
    if (length < 2) {
        newName = "000" + name;;
    }
    if (length < 3) {
        newName = "00" + name;
    }
    if (length < 4) {
        newName = "0" + name;
    } else {
        return name;
    }
    orderDTO.setName(newName);
    return nameTransform(orderDTO);
}
```

but i am not sure why you need the recursion in the last line

Your orderTransform would now look like this:

```
public InvoiceRequestDTO orderTransformer(OrderDTO orderDTO)  {
    return new InvoiceRequestDTO(nameTransform(orderDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use `new OrderDto()`, it has no name field thats why you get nullpointer.

```
return new InvoiceRequestDTO(OrderDto.nameFormatted());

class OrderDto {
.... 
    public String nameFormatted(){
        // check name
        if(this.name == null) {
             return "";
        }

        return String.format("%4s", this.name).replace(' ', '0');
    }
}
```